# Using htmlentities() in a BBCode-supporting textarea to stop XSS

Tags: php, xss, javascript, bbcode

I want to have a text area to post stuff to the database with BBCode. So, I downloaded a JavaScript code (to write in the specific BBCode when the image is clicked) but it didn't transform the text.

There are images of letters above the text area like B, I and U. When I click one of them, maybe B, the JavaScript inserts `[b][/b]`
to the text area. But when I submit the text with some other text in the bold BBcode, it doesn't make the text bold.

So, I thought this would work:

```
str_replace('[', '<', $_POST['text']);    
str_replace(']', '>', $_POST['text']);
```

It worked but I can't add `htmlentities()` now which I've been using to prevent XSS. So, what other options do I have to stop XSS?

Comment: is this a security question? I'm not seeing security implications here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing BBCode in a safe way that does not open the doors to XSS hell is a tricky task, and there have been many failed attempts. As you yourself note, the way you currently do it is vulnerable to XSS - all you need to do is post `[script src="evil.js"]`. Just using `htmlentities()` will not solve this for you, it is much more complex. This [blog](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/09/bbcode-wont-protect-you-from-xss.html) illustrates the problem neatly.

So I would not recommend you to try to implement your own BBCode interpreter. Instead I would look at existing libraries, either in PHP or client side in JavaScript and evaluate their security record. Some places to start:

- [The PHP BBCode extention](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)
- [Some different JavaScript options at NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=bbcode)

To add an extra layer of security you can run the generated HTML through a HTML sanitizer designed to "sandbox" HTML and keep any unwanted tags or attributes out (like `script` or `onerror`) in case the BBCode library should fail you. Some examples:

- [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) (for PHP)
- [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) (for JavaScript)

Do note that I have not evaluated the security of these libraries. Perhaps there are better alternatives - these are just provided here as examples. Whatever library you pick, you will need to look at its track record and decide for yourself if you trust it or not. And as usual, make sure to keep the libraries updated.

As [SilverlightFox](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/8340/silverlightfox) says in comments, as third layer of defense (for browsers that support it) you can set a [content security policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) that disallows inline scripts.

Comment: Also implementation of a [content security policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) if possible will mitigate any bypasses discovered within those HTML sanitizers.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Good point! I will add that to my answer since it can not be said to many times.